# Proper way to rollback on DB connection fail in Django

Tags: python, django, database, rollback

This is more of a design question than anything else.

Until recently I have been using Django with SQLite in my development environment, but I have now changed to PostgreSQL for production. My app is deployed with Heroku, and after some days I realized that they do random maintenance to the DB and it goes down during a few minutes.

For example, having a model with 3 tables, one `Procedure` which each of them point to a `ProcedureList`, and a `ProcedureList` can have more than one `Procedure`. A `ProcedureUser` which links a `ProcedureList` and a user and sets some specific variables for the user on that `ProcedureList`. Finally there is a `ProcedureState` which links a `Procedure` with its state for an specific user.

On my app, in one of the views I have a function that modifies the DB in the following way:

```
user = request.user
plist = ProcedureList.objects.get(id=idFromUrl)
procedures = Procedure.objects.filter(ProcedureList=pList)

pUser = ProcedureUser(plist, user, someVariables)
pUser.save()

for procedure in procedures:
    pState = ProcedureState(plist, user, pUser, procedure, otherVariables)    
    pState.save()
```

So what I'm thinking now, is that if Heroku decides to go into maintenance between those `object.save()` calls, we will have a problem. The later calls to `.save()` will fail and the DB will be corrupted. The request by the user will of course fail and there will be no way to rollback the previous insertions, because the connection with the DB is not possible.

My question is, in case of a DB fail (given by Heroku maintenance, network error or whatever), how are we supposed to correctly rollback the DB? Shall we make a list of insertions and wait for DB to go up again to roll them back?

I am using Python 3 and Django 4 but I think this is more of a general question than specific to any platform.

Comment: You can wrap the logic in a *transaction* that will be committed *atomically*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in case of a DB fail (given by Heroku maintenance, network error or whatever), how are we supposed to correctly rollback the DB?

This is solved by databases through [*atomic transactions* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). An *atomic* transaction is a set of queries that are committed *all* or *none*. It is thus *not* possible that for such transaction, certain queries are applied whereas others are not.

Django offers a [`transaction` *context manager* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) to perform work in a transaction:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    user = request.user
    plist = ProcedureList.objects.get(id=idFromUrl)
    procedures = Procedure.objects.filter(ProcedureList=pList)
    
    pUser = ProcedureUser(plist, user, someVariables)
    pUser.save()
    
    ProcedureState.objects.bulk_create([
        ProcedureState(plist, user, pUser, procedure, otherVariables)
        for procedure in procedures
    ])
```

At the end of the context block, it will *commit* the changes. This means that if the database fails in between, the actions will not be committed, and the block will raise an exception (usually an `IntegrityError`).

---

> **Note**: Django has a [**`.bulk_create(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to create *multiple* items with a *single* database query, minimizing the bandwidth between the database and the application layer. This will usually outperform creating items in a loop.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Quick question, is this something that most frameworks have?

Comment: @Ipares12: it is something that (nearly) all databases offer, so I would expect that mature  frameworks offer this. If not you can make SQL queries with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and end with `COMMIT` to update the database at the end of the transaction.